# Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, error-handling, kotlin

So I opened up a new project in Android studio 3.2 without kotlin or c++ support. When I try to view the design for activity_main.xml, all I see is "waiting for build to finish". I learn later on that this is because gradle sync failed. So I go to File>Sync Project with Gradle Files to try syncing again. During syncing, I get the error:

Gradle sync failed: Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-reflect/1.2.0/kotlin-reflect-1.2.0.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
Enable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project

And when I enable gradle offline mode, I get:

Gradle sync failed: No cached version of org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.2.0 available for offline mode.

The thing is, this problem is not from my end since, at the moment I type this, opening that link in a browser leads to an "error 404 not found" page.

So how do I go about this. I don't intend to use kotlin anytime soon. Is there a way to make android studio bypass that download? Is there a way to set it up manually? I should add that I'd very much like to use Android studio offline, and I don't want to connect to the internet everytime I start a new project. Thank you.

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-reflect/1.2.0 Show me that it is available in mavenCentral() and some others. Just add mavenCentral() as a repository to your build.gradle

Comment: I get similar errors from that repository as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here is What worked for me:

1. Remove lifecycle dependencies and sync
2. disable offline mode
3. now add all the lifecycle dependencies and sync

Thank you.